# How to pass different URL to webView from some buttons in swift?

Tags: swift

I have some buttons in first view controller and a webView in second view controller. How to pass different url from different buttons to the webView? For example, the first button will leads to a google website and the second one is Facebook but using the same webView. Do I need to create different segues for each button or just one? If using just one, where should I start pulling that blue line (that line when you hold the control key)?

In first viewController:

```
class CafesView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topBar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: MDCFloatingButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button4: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button5: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button6: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button7: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button8: MDCRaisedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button9: MDCRaisedButton!

    let cafes = [
        "Banana Joe's",
        "College Eight Cafe",
        "Global Village",
        "Iveta",
        "Oakes Cafe",
        "Perk Coffee Bar",
        "Stevenson Coffee House",
        "Terra Fresca",
        "Vivas"
    ]

    var urlToPass: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        topBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        topBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        topBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        topBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        button1.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button2.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button3.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button4.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button5.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button6.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button7.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button8.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button9.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    }

    @IBAction func bananaJoes(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://dining.ucsc.edu/pdf/banana-joes-menu.pdf"
    }

    @IBAction func collegeEightCafe(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://dining.ucsc.edu/pdf/c8-menu.pdf"
    }

    @IBAction func globalVillage(_ sender: Any) {
        urlToPass = "https://www.foodbooking.com/ordering/restaurant/menu?restaurant_uid=d368abee-3ccc-40d7-be7f-3ca5d4cbd513&glfa_cid=1263531392.1571083521&glfa_t=1571083566919"
    }

    @IBAction func iveta(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://iveta.com/pages/iveta-ucsc-menu"
    }

    @IBAction func oakesCafe(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://dining.ucsc.edu/pdf/oakes-menu-2019-20.pdf"
    }

    @IBAction func perkCoffeeBar(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://google.com" //This url is just a placeholder
    }

    @IBAction func stevensonCoffeeHouse(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://dining.ucsc.edu/pdf/stevenson-coffee-house-menu.pdf"
    }

    @IBAction func terraFresca(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://dining.ucsc.edu/terra-fresca/pdf/terra-fresca-menu.pdf"
    }

    @IBAction func vivas(_ sender: UIButton) {
        urlToPass = "https://dining.ucsc.edu/pdf/vivas-menu.pdf"
    }

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? CafesMenu else { return }

        destination.detailURL = urlToPass
        urlToPass = nil
    }

}
```

In the second one:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class CafesMenu: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    var detailURL: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("URL Requested: \(detailURL)")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let url = URL(string: detailURL!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use `prepareForSegue:sender:` to set a property in your destination view controller. `prepareForSegue:sender:` will be called before your initial view controller segues to any destination view controller. Within this function, we can check which button was pressed and set the appropriate URL in the destination view controller accordingly.

**This approach will allow you to use any segue between your buttons and your destination view controller. This means, you simply have to drag the blue line from the buttons to the view controller you want to segue to.**

**1.** Within your storyboard, create a segue between your first view controller and your destination view controller. This is done by holding control, clicking on the first view controller in the interface builder, and dragging over the destination view controller. Then choose a segue type:

[image]

Now, select this segue and give it the `Identifier` "InitialVCToDestinationVC" in the attributes inspector:

[image]

**2.** Make a property called `urlToPass` of type `URL` in your initial view controller:

```swift
class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    var urlToPass: URL!

    @IBAction func googleButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func facebookButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

**3.** Make a property called `receivedUrl` in the destination view controller:

```swift
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    var receivedUrl: URL!

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let request = URLRequest(url: receivedUrl)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

**4.** Set the `urlToPass` depending on which button is pressed and use the `prepareForSegue:sender:` function to set the destination view controller's url accordingly. Then, make use of `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` to perform the segue with identifier `InitialVCToDestinationVC`.

```swift
class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    var urlToPass: URL!

    @IBAction func googleButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        urlToPass = URL(string: "www.google.com")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "InitialVCToDestinationVC", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func facebookButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        urlToPass = URL(string: "www.facebook.com")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "InitialVCToDestinationVC", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        guard let destination = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController else { return }

        destination.receivedUrl = urlToPass
        urlToPass = nil
    }
}
```

**5. (optional)** Make use of the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method within `InitialViewController` and check whether or not `urlToPass` is valid. If `urlToPass` is valid, perform the segue, else present an alert.

```swift
class InitialViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let urlToPass = urlToPass {
            // check if your application can open the NSURL instance
            if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlToPass) {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot open URL.", message: "This is an invalid URL.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(ok)
                present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlToPass)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

End result:

[image]

Here's a link to the Xcode project I made the above gif from: https://github.com/ChopinDavid/PrepareForSegue

Comment: This works almostly. I actually have nine different buttons with 9 url. The weird thing is: the first five buttons works really well but from 6th button, when I click it, the app crashes because the url is nil. I did the same thing to all nine buttons but why there're only five of them works?

Comment: May be an invalid url, can you show some of the code so I can maybe diagnose the issue?

Comment: I don't really wanna post these url here because I don't wanna mess up with copyright stuff so do you have any messengers or kinda stuff so I can send it to you?

Comment: If you give me a few minutes, I can actually edit the code to check if the url is valid and have it present a pop up if the URL is invalid for you

Comment: I don't think the urls are invalid because I try to print the url string from second viewController and it shows nil so it means the webkit just simply doesn't receive anything.

Comment: I added a fifth step that checks that valid urls are being passed. Can you update the code and check on the links in question to make sure they are valid? If not, you will receive an alert in-app. I updated the githup repository as well if you need to see where to put the code.

Comment: Is the app crashing within the `viewWillAppear` of `CafesMenu`?

Comment: I added the alert but the alert never pop up. But the url seems working now except one problem: if I click the 6th button which is perk coffee bar, nothing happens. I need to click it twice to open the google webpage. After that, even though I click other button which should open other url, it presents the last url from the last button I clicked.

Comment: And yes, it crashes in cafesMenu because the url is nil.

Comment: Is it crashing at all, or is it just the wrong url now?

Comment: oh btw, because I'm converting the url in cafesMenu, I added a line in your shouldPerformSegue function: `let url = URL(string: urlToPass)`. Is it because of this line of code? Also, should I remove the prepare function?

Comment: The app doesn't crash now but has the issue I described above.

Comment: No need to remove the prepare function, but I would try to implement it the way I have it in the code, that is we pass a `URL` to `CafesMenu` instead of a `String`.

Comment: On my end, I am able to use a large number of buttons without issue.

Comment: Actually its the same result. You need to click twice to present the second viewController and the next button clicked shows the last webpage. If I remove the shouldPerformSegue, it still crashes.

Comment: I figured it out, I will edit my answer so that it makes more sense.

Comment: I found out the issue as to why the wrong url would sometimes pass. `prepareForSegue:sender:` is sometimes called before the actual `@IBAction` code. So the segue would perform before the `urlToPass` is set.

To get around this, I made edits to step 1 and step 4. We are now using a single segue between `InitialViewController` and `DestinationViewController`. We then call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` to ensure that `urlToPass` is set before the segue is performed.

Note that this doesn't address why you need to sometimes click the link twice. It seems to be a WKWebView bug.

Comment: The reason we sometimes have to click twice, is that when the `WKWebView`'s url is sometimes set, we are getting an error: `2019-10-14 16:16:59.617267-0500 Test[3347:768640] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1064e4f00 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()`

Comment: It seems that if we wait a couple of seconds before clicking a new url, we don't have to click twice. Maybe closing and reloading a `WKWebView` too quickly just doesn't work. This may warrant a new question. Check out the updated github repo if you're curious about any of the code.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate this. And yes, that processAssertionWasInvalidated error pops up a lot.

Comment: Yeah I know, not sure what we could really do about it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code snippet to pass the urlParameter to second viewcontroller

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController{


    func googleActionButton() {
        let vc = SecondViewController()
        vc.urlToOpen = "www.google.com"
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func facebookActionButton() {
        let vc = SecondViewController()
        vc.urlToOpen = "www.facebook.com"
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{

    var urlToOpen = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        //  set webview url to the 'urlToOpen' which you received from FirstViewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create an `enum WebURL` with all the url cases that you want to open, i.e.

```
enum WebURL {
    case google
    case facebook

    var url: String {
        switch self {
        case .google:
            return "https://www.google.com"
        case .facebook:
            return "https://www.facebook.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Next, in `FirstVC`, in the `UIButton's` `@IBAction` open `SecondVC` using the `WebURL` instance corresponding to that particular button, i.e.

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController{
    @IBAction func openGoogle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.openSecondVC(with: WebURL.google.url)
    }

    @IBAction func openFacebook(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.openSecondVC(with: WebURL.facebook.url)
    }

    func openSecondVC(with urlString: String) {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC {
            vc.urlString = urlString
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use `urlString` in `SecondVC` to configure your `webView`, i.e.

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    var urlString: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Setup your webView using urlString here...
    }
}
```